# What does this Object.assign({}, ...array.map(/*...*/)) code do here

Tags: javascript, dictionary, arguments, assign, spread-syntax

I have cloned this repo from github and I am unable to understand what's happening in the code.

`words` in the code is an array of words.

```
const wordDictionary = Object.assign({}, ...words.map((x) => ({ [x]: x })));
```

Comment: It's creating an object where each word of the array becomes a property of that object, returning the said word. You'll be alble to get word like this : wordDictionnary.foo // return "foo". Or wordDictionnary["bar"] // return "bar".

Answer (score 3):

It's taking an array (of strings, since you said it's an array of words; but it would work with numbers or Symbols too) and converting it to an object where both the names and values of the properties are the same. So for example, `["an", "example"]` becomes `{an: "an", example: "example"}`:

```js
const words = ["an", "example"];
const wordDictionary = Object.assign({}, ...words.map((x) => ({ [x]: x })));
console.log(wordDictionary);
```

It does it by mapping each array element to an object with one property (named by the array element, with the value of the array element) and then assigning all of those objects to a single target object.

For instance, with my `["an", "example"]` array, the steps are:

1. Do the mapping, turning:

   ```
   ["an", "example"]
   ```

   into

   ```
   [{an: "an"}, {example: "example"}]
   ```
2. [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) that array out into discrete arguments to [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with a blank target object. So

   ```
   Object.assign({}, ...[{an: "an"}, {example: "example"}])
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   Object.assign({}, {an: "an"}, {example: "example"})
   ```
3. Use `Object.assign` to assign the properties from those objects to the first one (the blank `{}` object).

---

It's worth noting that the code is overcomplicated. It would be much simpler just to use a loop:

```
const wordDictionary = {};
for (const word of words) {
    wordDictionary[word] = word;
}
```

Separately, dictionaries like this are better handled by [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instances:

```
const wordDictionary = new Map();
for (const word of words) {
    wordDictionary.set(word, word);
}
```

or in this specific case (since the key and value are the same) a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```
const wordDictionary = new Set(words);
```

Comment: T.J Thank you so much. You really made me feel enjoying understanding all this. Well, I have some more lines specifically to ask, if you have time.

Comment: @UsmanKhan - I do briefly (I should be working :-D ).